# Is it possible to adjust the vertical size of the Unity launcher?

Tags: 11.10, unity, gui

I want to make the bottom of the Unity launcher stop a little higher, is this possible? This isn't related to width or icon size. Searching turned up nothing about this. This is on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: can I ask why?  what do you want to do underneath the space that would be created ?

Comment: @fossfreedom: My guess is that he needs bottom panel not to be covered by launcher panel

Comment: ... oh I see - possibly wants to add a gnome-panel/xfce-panel etc at the bottom of the screen...

Comment: Yes, an Xfce panel would go in the space. I might try to look through the source for an option.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say yes, but my gut tells me no. Currently, there isn't much customization available for the Unity Launcher. While 12.04 promises to be better for Unity customization, currently, we're stuck with how Unity looks. To my knowledge, the size is set in stone. If someone, perhaps, were to make a CCSM plugin or something, you may have a shot. I think this would be a brilliant idea myself, but I have to unfortunately say that no, that's not possible as of yet. :(